# Collapsible items control in wpf - "System.Windows.Data Error: 4"

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, itemscontrol, togglebutton

I am creating a Windows app using C# and WPF, using MVVM. I am trying to create a collapsible items control, in order to display items from a collection. When expanding each item, a groupbox containing the item's properties should be displayed. I have the following inside a UserControl:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="GlyphBrush" Color="#444" />
<ControlTemplate x:Key="toggleButtonTemplate" TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Grid
        Width="15"
        Height="13"
        Background="Transparent">
        <Path x:Name="ExpandPath"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          VerticalAlignment="Center" 
          Margin="1,1,1,1"
          Fill="{StaticResource GlyphBrush}"
          Data="M 4 0 L 8 4 L 4 8 Z"/>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked"
             Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Data"
              TargetName="ExpandPath"
              Value="M 0 4 L 8 4 L 4 8 Z"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
<Style x:Key="toggleButtonStyle" TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource toggleButtonTemplate}" />
</Style>

<BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="VisibilityOfBool" />

<Style x:Key="CollapsibleListStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="Control.Margin" Value="5" />
                <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" Focusable="False">
                                </ContentPresenter>
                                <ToggleButton x:Name="toggleButton"  
                                    Grid.Column="1" IsChecked="False" Margin="3.5" 
                                      Style="{StaticResource toggleButtonStyle}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<WrapPanel>
    <ItemsControl Name="itemsList"
                  Style="{StaticResource CollapsibleListStyle}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModel.Items}"
                  Margin="0,0">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Vertical"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Column="0" 
                      FontWeight="DemiBold" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <GroupBox Header="Properties" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" 
                      Visibility="{Binding ElementName=toggleButton, 
                        Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityOfBool}}">
                        <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5">
                                <TextBlock Text="Code: "/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCode}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5">
                                <TextBlock Text="Key: "/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemKey}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </WrapPanel>
                    </GroupBox>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</WrapPanel>
```

This produces the following error at runtime:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with
>   reference 'ElementName=toggleButton'.
>   BindingExpression:Path=IsChecked; DataItem=null; target element
>   is 'GroupBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Visibility' (type 
>   'Visibility')

so the toggle button is not displayed. 
At a different place in my application, I have used the above, but replaced ItemsControl with a ListBox, to get a collapsible list box, and the code works as it should. 
However, here I do not want the selection functionality.

Can anyone please help with this?

Thank you, Brian

Comment: I don't see any binding to `toggleButtonModel`...

Comment: Yes, that was supposed to be `toggleButton`. Copied the wrong output line. I have edited the question. The binding should be in the Groupbox's Visibility property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always specify the `TargetType` if you know it, your style does not apply properly because you make it generic by not setting it and at the same time setting properties which do not exist on the container and hence are ignored.

Change the `TargetType` to `ContentPresenter` and you will no longer be able to set a `Template`:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
        <Setter Property="Template"> <!-- will throw an error -->
```

You need to move everything into the `ItemTemplate` as there is no `ControlTemplate` to be set.

Comment: But it did work. I think they are in the same scope, isn't that the purpose of `ContentPresenter`? The change I am not sure of is at line `<ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">`. That used to be `<ControlTemplate TargetType={x:Type ListBoxItem}>` when using a `ListBox`.

Comment: @BrianDay: The container in an `ItemsControl` should be a `ContentPresenter` while in a `ListBox` it obviously is a `ListBoxItem`. You should not even be able to change the template as `ContentPresenters` have no such property, the template will not be applied for that reason and hence the element is not found.

Comment: I see. Ended up using a `ListBox` with no check-box functionality instead. Anyway, thanks a lot.